# Перевернуть букву

Tags: python, строки

имеется строка
"a"
Как из её сделать "ɐ"?

Comment: Я думаю, что простых способов нет, потому что эти символы имеют различные коды `Unicode` (`U+0061` и `U+0250` соответственно). Как вариант, можно составить словарь вида `{'a': 'ɐ'}` для всего алфавита и побуквенно заменять символы в цикле.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40356508/how-to-rotate-a-character-or-string-by-90-or-180-degree-in-python

Comment: pip install upsidedown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pip3 install upsidedown`

```
import upsidedown
print(upsidedown.transform('hello world!'))
```